# hibernate and sql connect

Tags: sql, hibernate

I try to make a project
I use hibernate to connect SQL but fail
I do not know why it cant run
  this is my project,please tell me why  thank

model  ZX.java:

```
public class ZX{private String zx01,zx02,zx03;//set&get}
```

order.hbm.xml

```
<class name="model.ZX" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true"  
       optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="zx_file">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="zx01" column="zx01"/>           
    </composite-id>
   <property column="zx01" name="zx01"/>
    <property column="zx02" name="zx02"/>
    <property column="zx03" name="zx03"/>
    </class>
```

control /controller.java

```
public java.util.List<model.ZX> findZX(){
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
//String hql = "from ZX where rownum<21" ;  
//java.util.List list = this.hibernateTemplate.find(hql);
 Criteria crit= session.createCriteria(ZX.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.like("zx01","T%"));
java.util.List<model.ZX> list2= crit.list();
 session.close();
    return list2;
}
```

pro /show.java

```
public class show implements java.io.Serializable{

private control.controller con;
   private java.util.List<model.ZX> zxtest;

public show() {
}public String search() {
    this.zxtest = this.con.findZX();     
    return null;
} }
```

my error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeibC.jpg)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pro.show.getZxtest(show.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1822)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
```

this is my project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gEMKtuEgmJnOvtaDXPPNoUxhChs2lvt1

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and the exact error message and stacktrace you get.  [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to used HQL that is hibernate query language. and config. that can control and connects the SQL to hibernate e.g exmple.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>  

<session-factory>  
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>  
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>  
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
<mapping resource="packagename/exmple.hbm.xml"/>//mapping file  
</session-factory>
```

Note: here u creating new table with help or create ddl . for update you can use update instand of create.

Comment: <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">tw</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">tw</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.....</property>
   <mapping resource="model/order.hbm.xml"/> 
  </session-factory>           i had create

Comment: this is my project:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gEMKtuEgmJnOvtaDXPPNoUxhChs2lvt1

Comment: checkout the jar files i dont know but i guess some jar files are missing.

Comment: hope you will get some help from this link. [hibernate](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-jpa-2-configuration-example)